# Woocommerce - сломана сортировка по умолчанию, где искать?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Магазин на wordpress + woocommerce

Предыдущий разработчик сделал сортировку по количеству товара. Причем изменения не в файле `functions.php` Какие файлы (не в теме! изменения в самом woocommerce) изменялись для этого? Как найти, чтобы переделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не советовал размножать костыли и рекомендую откатить все файлы и добавить сортировку через хуки. Но отвечая на поставленный вопрос, то изменения должны были коснуться следующих файлов:

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php

```
function woocommerce_catalog_ordering()
```

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php

```
function get_catalog_ordering_args()
```

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/settings/class-wc-settings-products.php

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', array() )
```